# What is the correct way to get the content of queryParams when redirecting using Router.navigate?

Tags: javascript, angular

When redirecting I try to pass information through queryParams so that it is processed in the destination, but queryParams is empty

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(({ token }) => {
    if (!token) {
      this.router.navigate([''], {
        queryParams: { message: 'Invalid URL' },
      });

      return;
    }

    // ...
  });
}
```

The above works as expected but when redirecting in case of missing token in the destination path I hope to obtain in the queryParam the value of the message `{message: 'Invalid URL'}` but it is always empty, here the implementation

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
    console.log(params);
  });
}
```

Here params is always empty

What is the correct way to get the content of queryParams when redirecting using Router.navigate?

**Update 1**

In the following repository [customer-app](https://github.com/ilmoralito/customer-app) the component `src/app/ orders/orders.component.ts` redirects to the customers path, where `src/app/customers/customers.component.ts` try gets the value of `queryParams`

**Update 2**

I was able to identify that the reason why the content of queryParams is lost is because before going to the destination path it is intercepted by a `canActivate` guard. In order to preserve queryParams when redirecting from guard I explicitly add queryParams as follows `this.activatedRoute.navigate(['/some/path'], { queryParams: route.queryParams });` This works. But when navigating to other routes the url in the address bar is not updated but the url of the first redirect is kept. Any ideas?

Comment: you should add another property to preserve the query params on navigation: https://angular.io/api/router/QueryParamsHandling

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have tried this option but queryParams remains empty

Comment: you're missing something, can you add a stackblitz

Comment: Sure, in a moment

Comment: I update the question, adding a demo repository

Comment: I just updated the question adding new information

Comment: kindly reproduce on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute
){}

const code = this.route.snapshot.queryParams?.code;
```